# How can I open a Corel Draw file in Adobe Creative Suite?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, corel-draw, adobe-creative-suite

I received some CorelDRAW files, and need to open them, preferably in Illustrator. But anything from the Adobe suit will do.

I do not have CorelDRAW and I have a Mac, is there a way to convert them?

There are a few websites that convert files, but I have close to 200 hundred files and the website doesn't handle that quantity.

Comment: The issue is probably that the CDR files are a newer version than your copy of Illustrator supports.

Comment: This site worked for me and allows multiple file uploads: http://www.zamzar.com/convert/cdr-to-ai/

Answer (score 7):

hey might be this info can help you..

Illustrator 9.0 or later able to open CDR files created with CorelDRAW 10 or earlier

Programs that open CDR files

1. CorelDRAW Graphics Suite X5
2. Corel PaintShop Photo Pro
3. Corel WordPerfect Office
4. ACD Systems Canvas 12
5. Adobe Illustrator CS5
6. Inkscape

irfan view might solve this please check this link...and its free also

http://www.freewaremission.com/2008/05/convert-cdr-files-with-irfanview/

Comment: Corel Draw is now at version X5 (i.e. 15) though.

Comment: 7. OpenOffice/LibreOffice Draw

Comment: CDR file is not opening in my adobe illustrator CC 2018.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you either buy Corel Draw, or ask your supplier to save the files as EPS.

Comment: +1 for EPS. CorelDraw EPS files can be wonky depending on the particular effect used, but it renders the file usable in a lot more applications.

Answer (score 3):

[Uniconvertor](http://sk1project.org/modules.php?name=Products&product=uniconvertor) can convert from a `.cdr` file to an `.ai` file among others.

"UniConvetor is used in Inkscape and Scribus projects as external tool for CorelDraw files importing. "

Answer (score 2):

i think, you better ask your supplier to export the files in PDF [high quality print] file format and send back only PDF file to you.
with PDF you can easily open and edit the files in illustrator or any Adobe programs. without loosing any details from from original files.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have a .cdr file, so I downloaded one here: http://vector4free.com/vectors/id/463

Illustrator allowed me to open it just fine. It [your file] may be bad (corrupt through email, or something to that effect).

See if you can open the file I did.

Also in Illustrator's  dialog window, you will find support for Corel Draw (take a look).

[image]

**edit:**

Forgot to mention that I just drug that file from my downloads to my dock. So you could potentially open quite a few at a time to process them.

Comment: Corel Draw is now at version X5 (i.e. 15) though.

Answer (score 1):

Download the trial version of [Corel](http://www.corel.com) to convert the file.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use online convert website, good for vidoes too. there's no email or registering either. this should work for your CDR file, justs coverts it to EPS
 online coverter

Comment: Hi there! You forgot the link :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this online converter -
[FilesConverter (cdr-to-ai)](https://filesconverter.com/cdr-to-ai)